# How to remove Groups from Project Role(Ex- Users Role) in particular project using API call

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

I want to remove groups in Users role in a given project using api call . How can i do that? I can remove all the groups and users using

```
jiraSoapService.removeAllRoleActorsByProject(authToken,remoteProject);
```

But i want to remove only groups of Role - Users how can i do that?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if the SOAP API allows that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [removeActorsFromProjectRole](http://docs.atlassian.com/rpc-jira-plugin/latest/com/atlassian/jira/rpc/soap/JiraSoapService.html#removeActorsFromProjectRole%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d,%20com.atlassian.jira.rpc.soap.beans.RemoteProjectRole,%20com.atlassian.jira.rpc.soap.beans.RemoteProject,%20java.lang.String%29) method from SOAP API:

```
jiraSoapService.removeActorsFromProjectRole(
    authToken,
    arrayOfGroupNames,
    projectRole,
    project,
    "atlassian-group-role-actor");
```

If you'd like to remove users and not groups, you should use "atlassian-user-role-actor" as the last argument for that method.